# Debian Dist-Upgrade to Jessie (8) - still init.d?

Tags: debian, systemd, debian-jessie

I dist-upgraded my debian-box and now I mention some strange behavior:

If I try to start services using systemctl I'm getting this error:

> Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unknown error -1

If I try to install systemd and systemd-sysv system tells me that it is already installed:

```
root@me:# apt-get install systemd systemd-sysv
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
systemd ist schon die neueste Version.
systemd-sysv ist schon die neueste Version.
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
```

`stat /proc/1/exe` shows me the following:

```
  Datei: „/proc/1/exe“ -> „/sbin/init (deleted)“
  Größe: 0          Blöcke: 0          EA Block: 1024   symbolische Verknüpfung
Gerät: 3h/3d    Inode: 1732        Verknüpfungen: 1
Zugriff: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Zugriff    : 2015-12-01 17:09:01.144203951 +0100
Modifiziert: 2015-10-25 15:22:40.855999829 +0100
Geändert   : 2015-10-25 15:22:40.855999829 +0100
 Geburt    : -
```

But /sbin/init is symlinked to systemd

```
ls -al /sbin/init
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Aug 29 17:45 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd
```

Any ideas how to get systemd working?

Comment: Maybe a reboot to force Debian to use the systemd init instead of the standard one ? But, wait, do you check that DBUS is working ?

Comment: How can I check DBUS?

Comment: "systemctl status dbus"

Comment: Did you restart the computer? Changing from old init to systemd requires a restart.

Comment: `systemctl status dbus
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unbekannter Fehler -1` but `service dbus status
[ ok ] dbus is running.`

Yes, I restarted the computer.